# Evaluate $\int_0^\frac{1}{16}\int_{y^{\frac{1}{4}}}^\frac{1}{4} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)}dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{16}\int_{y^{\frac{1}{4}}}^\frac{1}{4} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)dx\,dy}$

My attempt:

Reverse the order of integration
[image]

Then the integral will be:
$$\displaystyle\int_{x^4}^\frac{1}{16}\int_{0}^\frac{1}{4} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)dx\,dy}$$

Using wolfram, this is what I found:
$$0.0154$$

But the correct answer is $-0.0085$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You didn't swap the $dx$ and $dy$ around in your new integral.

Comment: @B.Goddard edited, but still got the wrong answer.

Comment: Original area doesn't contains (0, 1/16), but new area does.

Comment: You still have a variable in your outside limits.  Carefully draw the area from the original integral and then recast the limits for the new integral based on the picture.  Don't try to cook up the limits algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration has two wings. Thus in reversing the order of integration you are going to have two integrals namely  $$\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{16}\int_{y^{\frac{1}{4}}}^\frac{1}{4} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)dx\,dy}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{x^4} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)dy\,dx} -$$

$$\displaystyle\int_{\frac {1}{4}}^\frac{1}{2}\int_{x^4}^\frac{1}{16} \cos{\left(16\pi x^5\right)dy\,dx}$$

Comment: I've attached my version for shading the area, did I shade the wrong area? I don't really get what you mean about two wings.

Comment: Your area is still problematic. Check the bounds for $x$ and $y$ carefully.